# Restoring k8s service account tokens

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-secrets

I'd like to restore a kubernetes service account token from a backup (which is actually just an export of the corresponding secret):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-service-account-token-lqrvp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: my-service-account
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
data:
  token: bXktc2ltcGxlLXRva2VuCg==
```

The secret has been applied successfully and was added to the service account:

```
# kubectl apply -f my-service-account.yaml
secret/my-service-account-token-lqrvp created

# kubectl describe sa my-service-account
Name:                my-service-account
Namespace:           my-namespace
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         kubernetes.io/service-account.name: my-service-account
Image pull secrets:  my-service-account-dockercfg-lv9hp
Mountable secrets:   my-service-account-token-lv9hp
Tokens:              my-service-account-token-lqrvp
Events:              <none>
```

Unfortunately, everytime I try to access the api using the token, I always get the error "The token provided is invalid or expired":

```
# kubectl login https://api.my-k8s-cluster.mydomain.com:6443 --token=my-simple-token
error: The token provided is invalid or expired
```

I know that the token is usually automatically generated by the controller-manager, but is restoring a token supported by kubernetes?

Comment: Is your real token a JWT one? As I remember only JWT tokens will work https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/cea1d4e20b4a7886d8ff65f34c6d4f95efcb4742/pkg/serviceaccount/jwt_test.go#L327 but I may be wrong

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, could you please add the `$ kubectl describe secret my-service-account-token-lqrvp`? I tried to reproduce your setup and the secret also had other data key and values like `namespace` and `ca.crt`. You also have a different secrets mentioned in your serviceaccount describe (`lqrvp` and `lv9hp`)